# How to create a function to hide rows based on a cell value in VBA EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I created this function to hide some rows based on a cell value.

```
Function myTest(Unit As String)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTING").Rows("15:16").Select
    If Unit = "XXX" Then
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        myTest= "1"
    End If
End Function
```

When the unit value is not "XXX" the functions works fine, but when it is "XXX", the cell that calls this function gets #VALUE!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a function? I see nothing returned and operations being performed on the spreadsheet. Therefore, I would swap Function and End Function out for Sub and End Sub. Moving on, at a glance your problem may be as simple as an innate problem with trying to hide the current selection. Excel is not going to like that. In reality, avoid selecting cells. That is a user interface concept which causes many problems when it is relied upon in code.

Comment: Upon rereading, I have a simple curiosity question... Are you trying to run this as a function in a cell?? If so, please reconsider.

Comment: I should clarify that you do have a return value but it is only in one code branch and this is still much better as a Sub than Function.

Comment: Functions run as UDF's from a formula in a worksheet cell have certain restrictions placed on them: pretty much all they can do is return a value to the cell with the formula - they cannot for example modify the sheet layout or update values in other cells. If you need to automate this kind of theing then use the worksheet's `_Change` or `_Calculate` event.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff thanks for helping me. I recently started programming in vba excel. I changed function to sub and I used it into a change event.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about returning whether the cells are now hidden, then you can keep it as a function. Otherwise make it a Sub and get rid of the `myTest = ...` line below. Selecting cells in VBA is almost always an awful idea. It is unreliable, buggy, and a huge slowdown. The following code is the most concise function I can give you to do this. It directly applies the True/False evaluation of `Unit = "XXX"` to the Hidden property of the rows. I added an explicit Boolean return type.

```
Function myTest(Unit As String) As Boolean
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5").Rows("15:16").EntireRow.Hidden = (Unit = "XXX")
    myTest = Not (Unit = "XXX")
End Function
```

To stay closer to your structure you could use a range object:

```
Function myTest(Unit As String) As String
    Dim rng As Range
    rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTING").Rows("15:16")
    If Unit = "XXX" Then
        rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        myTest = "0"
    Else
        rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        myTest= "1"
    End If
End Function
```

Or you could use a With block:

```
Function myTest(Unit As String) As String
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTING").Rows("15:16")
        If Unit = "XXX" Then
            .EntireRow.Hidden = True
            myTest = "0"
        Else
            .EntireRow.Hidden = False
            myTest= "1"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```